# Configuring FAST 2010 Beta for SharePoint

Tags: fast-search, search

I've followed all the instructions and it seems to crawl OK etc but in my fast search center when i do a search I get the following error in the core search results Web Part:

Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.

I can't see anything useful in the SharePoint logs either at this stage.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I got it to work fine.  You can follow my steps [here](http://blogs.architectingconnectedsystems.com/blogs/cjg/archive/2009/11/28/FAST-Search-Step-by-Step-Install.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about FAST 2010, but I was under the impression that FAST used different webparts to render search results instead of the core search results webpart which is typically used for SharePoint Server.  The error though kind of sounds like they are using a dataview webpart or something to render the results and there is something wrong with the XSLT.  That's what I would check first to see if there is any custom XSL in the webpart properties and make sure that XSL looks well formed.

Comment: I created a search center using the fast search center site type so I'm presuming all the config would be done already unless the out of the box template is broken. That's why I am keen to know if anyone else has it working :)